# Trying to add Rows in my DataTables using fnAddTr. Getting "fnAddTr is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two datatables on a single page. Think of them as one table for packages waiting to be picked up, and one table for items that have been picked up. When I perform a pickup for an item, the idea is to "move" the item row from one table to the other one. That catch is that there are different columns for the two tables, so when the "pickup"action is performed via an ajax call, I delete the old rows from the first table and I am receiving back an array of "..." strings that contains the new HTML for the various item rows that have been completed with the new columns for the second table.

When I perform the task, I receive the error "TypeError: the_datatable2.fnAddTr is not a function"

I have ensured, obviously that the JS Files are being imported correctly.

**SCRIPTS IN FOOTER**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/api/fnAddTr.js"></script>
```

I have ensured that my DataTables object exists (it's displayed properly on the screen, so I know it's there), and I've also ensured the string is being turned properly into a DOM element (right?).

**AJAX CALLBACK**

```
for(var x = 0; x < data.table_rows.length; x++){

    var table_row = $(data.table_rows[x])[0];

    console.log(the_datatable2); // See Output Below
    console.log(table_row); // See DOM Item Output Below

    the_datatable2.fnAddTr(table_row);
}
```

I am at a bit of a loss. I can usually iron these out after enough massaging, but this just doesn't seem to want to budge. I've include JS log output below.

Thanks in advance for any guidance

**console.log(the_datatable2);**

[image: console.log(the_datatable2);]

**console.log(table_row);**

[image]

Comment: Well may be the support is removed. The [doc](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnAddTr)  says the function is deprecated and use `rows.add()` or `row.add()` instead if you are using DataTables 1.10+ . If not use legacy version of datatables.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! Thank you!